# Powershell to write the retrieved data on a single row- SQL

Tags: sql, powershell

I got a SQL health check report, for which I wanted to add the "version" column which was not there, I edited the code and was able to get the data, however It is writing on all the rows of the column, I just want it on one single row.

This is what I did to get the version

```
$sqlver = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') "$instance1"
$sqlver= $sqlver | select version
```

The output image is here:
[image: output]

Just starting off with PowerShell, any direction will be appreciated.

Full Script:

```
$Fbkp=48
$Dbkp=24
$i=$null
$s=$null

$Servers = Get-Content "serverlist location"

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | out-null

$bodyM = "<table cellpadding=3 cellspacing=1  bgcolor=#FF8F2F style='font-family:verdana; font-size:7pt;'>"
$bodyM += "<tr bgcolor=#DDDDDD><TH>InstanceName</TH><TH>Status</TH>"
$body = "<table cellpadding=3 cellspacing=1  bgcolor=#FF8F2F style='font-family:verdana; font-size:7pt;'>"
$body += "<tr bgcolor=#DDDDDD><TH>ServerName</TH><TH>Instance Name</TH><TH>Version</TH><TH>SQL Server Agent</TH><TH>Uptime</TH><TH>Databases</TH><TH>Status</Th><TH>Size(MB)</TH><TH>DataSpaceUsage(KB)</Th><TH>SpaceAvailable(KB)</TH><TH>RecoveryModel</TH><TH>Full Backup</TH><TH>Differential Backup</TH><TH>Log Backup</TH></tr>"

ForEach ($Server in $Servers) {
$s=$null

Try{
Get-WmiObject -computer $server win32_service -ErrorAction Stop >.\tmp.txt
$instances = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $server win32_service | where {(($_.name -eq "MSSQLSERVER") -or ($_.name -like "MSSQL$*"))} | select-object name
}catch {  $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message ; $errrun11=11

$body += "<tr bgcolor=white align=center><td><b>$server</b></td><TD colspan=12 align=left><font color=red>$ErrorMessage</font></TD></tr>"
}

If ($errrun11 -ne "11") {
foreach ($instance in $instances) {
$Instname="$($instance.name)"

if ($instance.name -like "MSSQLSERVER") { $instance1=$server} else {
$instance =  $($instance.name).Split("$")
$instance1="$server\$($instance[1])"
$Instname="$($instance[1])"
}

$instance1

try {

$srv = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') "$instance1"
$SJruns=$srv.JobServer.Jobs | Where-Object {$_.CurrentRunStatus -eq "running"} | Select Name,LastRunDate,nextrundate,CurrentRunStatus
$dbstest=$srv.Databases
$dbstest >tmp.txt
} catch {$ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message; $runerr=7


If ($s -eq $null) {$Srnm=$server} else {$Srnm=$null}

$s++
$body += "<tr bgcolor=white align=center><td><b>$Srnm</b></td><td><b>$instance1</b></td><TD colspan=11 align=left><font color=red>$ErrorMessage</font></TD></tr>"
}

If ($runerr -ne 7) {
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | out-null
$i=$null

                $SQLServer=$null

               $SQLServer = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') $instance1 

                try{ Foreach($Database in $SQLServer.Databases){ break}} catch {$SQLServer=$null}

if (!$SQLServer) { $body += "<tr bgcolor=#D3D3D3 align=center><TD colspan=10 align=center><font color=red><B>$instance</B></font></TD></tr>" } else {

                #$body += "<tr bgcolor=#D3D3D3 align=center><TD colspan=10 align=center><B>$Server</B></TD></tr>"


$UpTime=$null

if($SQLServer.Databases['tempdb']) {

        $udb = $SQLServer.Databases['tempdb']
        $CreateDate = $udb.CreateDate        
        $Time = (Get-Date) – $CreateDate

        $UpTime ="$($Time.DAYS) days $($Time.HOURS) hrs $($Time.MINUTES) mins $($Time.SECONDS) sec"

                }  

                Foreach($Database in $SQLServer.Databases)
                {
                $out=$Database.LastBackupDate
        $outt=((Get-Date) - $out).TotalHours

        $out1=$Database.LastDifferentialBackupDate
        $outt1=((Get-Date) - $out1).TotalHours

        $out2=$Database.LastLogBackupDate
        $outt2=((Get-Date) - $out2).TotalHours

                if($Database.LastBackupDate -eq "01/01/0001 00:00:00") {$LFBD="No Full Backup"} 
                elseif ( $outt -gt '48' -and ($Database.Name -NotContains ('master','model','msdb','tempdb') ) ) {$LFBD="<font color=red >$out</font>"}
                else { $LFBD=$out}

                if($Database.LastDifferentialBackupDate -eq "01/01/0001 00:00:00") { $LDBD ="No Diff Backup"}
                elseif ( $outt1 -gt '24') {$LDBD="<font color=red >$out1</font>"}
                else { $LDBD=$out1}


                if($Database.LastLogBackupDate -eq "01/01/0001 00:00:00") { $LLBD ="No Log Backup"}
                elseif($Database.RecoveryModel -Match "Simple"){$LLBD ="N/a"}

                elseif ( $outt2 -gt '24') {$LLBD="<font color=red >$out2</font>"}
                else { $LLBD=$out2}

$sqlver = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') "$instance1"
$sqlver= $sqlver | select version


$Sqlagt = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $server win32_service | where {($_.displayname -like "SQL Server Agent*") -and ($_.displayname -like "*($instname)*")}
If ($($Sqlagt.state) -eq "Running") {$AGTsts="<font color=green>$($Sqlagt.state)</font>"} else { $AGTsts="<font color=red>$($Sqlagt.state)</font>"}

If ($($Database.Status) -like "*offline*") {$DB1sts="<font color=red>$($Database.Status)</font>"} 

elseIf ($($Database.Status) -like "*normal*") {$DB1sts="<font color=green>Online</font>"} 
else { $DB1sts="$($Database.Status)"}


If ($s -eq $null) {$Srnm=$server} else {$Srnm=$null}
If ($i -eq $null) {$Instnm=$instance1; $Agtst=$Agtsts; $upt=$uptime} else {$Instnm=$Agtst=$upt=$null}

$i++
$s++

                $body += "<tr bgcolor=white align=left><TD><b>$srnm</b></TD><TD><b>$Instnm</b></TD><TD><b>$sqlver</b></TD><TD>$Agtst</TD><TD>$upt</TD><TD><b>$($Database.Name)</b></TD><TD>$DB1sts</TD></TD><TD>$($Database.Size)</TD><TD>$($Database.DataSpaceUsage)</TD><TD>$($Database.SpaceAvailable)</TD><TD>$($Database.RecoveryModel)</TD><TD>$LFBD</TD><TD>$LDBD</TD><TD>$LLBD</TD></TR>"

$i++
$s++
                } 
} 


} else {$runerr=$ErrorMessage=$null}#If ($runerr -ne 7)

} 

} else {$errrun11=$null} #If ($errrun11 -ne "11")

} 

$body += "</Table>"


$msgBody = "<table  cellpadding=3 cellspacing=1  bgcolor=#FF8F2F>"
$msgBody += "<tr align=center>"
$msgBody += "<td bgcolor=#DDDDDD><FONT face=Verdana size=1.5 ><b>SQL Server(s) Health Report</b></font></td>"
$msgBody += "</tr>"
$msgBody += "<tr>"
$msgBody += "<td bgcolor=white><FONT face=Verdana size=1.5 >$body</font></td>"
$msgBody += "</tr>"
$msgBody += "</table>"

$date= get-date -format dd-MM-yyyy

$File = "outputfile.htm" 
If ((Test-Path $File) -eq $true){ Remove-Item $File }
Add-Content -Path $File  -Value $msgBody
"Created file - $File"

exit
go
```

Comment: `$sqlver= $sqlver | select version` => `$sqlver= $sqlver | select -expandproperty version` for starters

Comment: Thanks Matt, that clears out the unwanted words captured in the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select a particular Column then that column should be first should be present in the query output of the sql.

Then you can select it using *Select-Object* . It would be better if you can post the entire script so that we can see how you are filtering the columns in the HTML report.

For getting the SQL version, you can try like this:

```
 $connectionString ="server=blrvdilities02;uid=sa; pwd=nextgen;Integrated Security=False;"
 $connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection -ErrorAction Stop 
 $connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
 try{
    $connection.Open()
    $locationquery = 'select @@Version as Version'
    $locationcommand = $connection.CreateCommand()
    $locationcommand.CommandText = $locationquery
    $locationresult = $locationcommand.ExecuteReader()
    $locationdt = new-object "System.Data.DataTable"
    $locationdt.Load($locationresult)
    $version = $locationdt.Version 
    }
   catch{
    $version=$_.Exception.Message;
    }

   Write-Output  $version
```

Comment: Thanks Ranadip, not sure if I can incorporate your suggestion since the script is fetching all that details under one loop if I am not wrong, I want to share the script here but its pretty long not fit for the comment, tried editing the post adding the script but it makes a mess.

UPDATE- Have updated the post with the script.

Comment: @Att: Put the script in github or pastebin and you can give us the link for the same. We can take a look at it then.

Comment: I have shared the script in the post, hopefully its under the right format.

Comment: @Att: i will check it once i will login from system. M from mobile right now.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the answer,

I had to declare it like this:

$v=$null (signifying the Column)

if ($v -eq $null) {$sqlver=$sqlver} else {$sqlver=$null}

$v++

on the body where there is

$i++

$s++

(by adding this)

$v++

That did the trick. Thanks Matt for clearing the result and Ranadip for taking the time to look into it. Appreciate it.

Comment: Ya that goes well.